# Generate multiple output files for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

i'm trying to generate a new output file from each existing file in a directory of .txt files. I want to check line by line in each file for two substrings. And append the lines that match that substring to each new output file.

I'm having trouble generating the new files.
This is what i currently have:

```
#!/bin/sh
# My first Script


success="(Compiling)\s\".*\"\s\-\s(Succeeded)"
failure="(Compiling)\s\".*\"\s\-\s(Failed)"
count_success=0
count_failure=0
for i in ~/Documents/reports/*;
do
        while read -r line;
        do
                if [[$success=~$line]]; then
                        echo $line >> output_$i
                        count_success++

                elif [[$failure=~$]]; then
                        echo $line >> output_$i
                        count_failure++
                fi
                done
        done
echo "$count_success of jobs ran succesfully"
echo "$count_failure of jobs didn't work"
~
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your shell scripts.
If you use Visual Studio Code, you could install "ShellCheck" (by Timon Wong) extension.

About your porgram.

- Assume bash
- Define different extensions for input and output files (really important if there are in the same directory)
- Loop on report, input, files only
- Clear output file
- Read input file
- `if` sequence:

  - `if [[ ... ]]`  with space after `[[` and before `]]`
  - spaces before and after operators (`=~`)
  - reverse operands order for operators `=~`
- Prevent globbing with `"..."`

```bash
#! /bin/bash

# Input file extension
declare -r EXT_REPORT=".txt"
# Output file extension
declare -r EXT_OUTPUT=".output"

# RE
declare -r success="(Compiling)\s\".*\"\s\-\s(Succeeded)"
declare -r failure="(Compiling)\s\".*\"\s\-\s(Failed)"

# Counters
declare -i count_success=0
declare -i count_failure=0

for REPORT_FILE in ~/Documents/reports/*"${EXT_REPORT}"; do
    # Clear output file
    : > "${REPORT_FILE}${EXT_OUTPUT}"

    # Read input file (see named file in "done" line)
    while read -r line; do

        # does the line match the success pattern ?
        if [[ $line =~ $success ]]; then
            echo "$line" >> "${REPORT_FILE}${EXT_OUTPUT}"
            count_success+=1
        # does the line match the failure pattern ?
        elif [[ $line =~ $failure ]]; then
            echo "$line" >> "${REPORT_FILE}${EXT_OUTPUT}"
            count_failure+=1
        fi

    done < "$REPORT_FILE"
done

echo "$count_success of jobs ran succesfully"
echo "$count_failure of jobs didn't work"
```

Comment: Very nice detailed suggestions. In addition, bash regex (ERE) doesn't support `\s`.

Comment: You could use `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s` or simply `\ ` for one space

Answer (score 1):

What about using `grep`?

```bash
success='Compiling\s".*"\s-\sSucceeded'
failure='Compiling\s".*"\s-\sFailed'
count_success=0
count_failure=0
for i in ~/Documents/reports/*; do
  (( count_success += $(grep -E "$success" "$i" | tee "output_$i" | wc -l) ))
  (( count_failure += $(grep -E "$failure" "$i" | tee -a "output_$i" | wc -l) ))
done
echo "$count_success of jobs ran succesfully"
echo "$count_failure of jobs didn't work"
```